# Laravel all images broken in VPS

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, deployment, vps

All Laravel images are broken after I deployed my app in Google VPS. Project folder, storage, bootstrap/cache folders have the right permissions followed by the instructions.

My nginx default path is: root /var/www/mysite/public

Images are inside public/img folder and called as below:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/img/picture-53.png') }}" alt="">
```

I have tried deleting **public/storage** and ran **php artisan storage:link** but nothing seems to work. Image paths I found in my browser's Inspect element are actually correct as *http://my-site.com/img/picture-53.png* and when I open it in the browser, I get:

```
The image "http://my-site.com/img/picture-53.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors
```

I have configured **config/filesystems.php** file as

```
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I haven't found the solution after googling for 7 days. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Check symlink creating does not block in your server config.

Comment: The `storage:link` as well as storage configuration are a bit of a red herring because `/img/picture-53.png` would be served directly from `public/img/...` and not from the local storage disk. If you want to make a URL to the public storage use  `Storage::disk('public')->url('img/picture-53.png')` or `asset('storage/img/picture-53.png')`

Comment: Solved!: Turns out, every image was corrupted during git push. Git encodes every image based on your .gitattributes file, so I solved this issue by setting "binary" for .jpg, jpeg, .png files.